# Distinction between [proofreading] and [copy-editing]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Do we really need both the [proofreading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofreading) and [copy-editing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-editing) tags? Do copyeditors not usually take care of proofreading too?

If we need the distinction, can the difference be made explicit on the tag wiki and the two tags cross-linked?

Answer (score 3):

No, authors proofread and copy editors do a host of things.  They are different processes.